# Black lines when zoomed out both in blender and unity,

Tags: texturing, uv

im having a problem with blender.

im making a roman house, and then created UV map and texture it.
for some reason, it's showing black lines between faces.

i re-arrange the faces in UV map so that it'll fill more blanks and then i enlarge it to get more details out of it.

This is the UV mapping, i expand the texture 2-3 px outside the UV map border to avoid color bleed. So all edge of the UV map is covered by the textures.

[image]

This is when i zoomed out in blender

[image]

This is in unity when i tested it

[image]

then i tried to make a texture where the walls are stick together in UV map and the line is not showing. But by doing so i reduce the quality of the texture.

**now my question is, do the faces in the UV map need to be placed close to each other when the actual face in the 3D mesh is side by side? (as in I can't re-arrange it to get more detail as i enlarge it)**

i've googled a few posts and most of the answer is because of color bleed due to the texture not covering the black lines of the UV. But i did expand the textures to 2-3 px outside the UV lines to avoid color bleed.

best regards.

Note:
black lines in unity only appear as I put a normal map to the material.